# Magento 1.9: Cronjob notification error

Tags: magento-1.9, reindex, crontab

I am getting magento cronjob error for indexing from this week i dont know how to get rid of i tried setting up cron like:

> sh /home/jsbfurniture/public_html/cron.sh
>
> sh /home/jsbfurniture/public_html/cron.php
>
> sh -f indexer.php reindexall

[image: check this image showing error]

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup the Magento cron?

you can check by using crontab -l using ssh/putty:

If cron is not set please add this using crontab -e

```
* * * * * /bin/bash /path of root directory where magento is installed/cron.sh
```